# glibc error while building linux from scratch

Tags: linux, makefile, glibc

The following error came up when i did 'make' of glibc-2.14.1 for LFS 7.1. I am using ubuntu as the host OS.

```
gcc ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/syslog.c -c -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -O2 -Wall -Winline 
-Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -g -Wstrict-prototypes -mpreferred-stack-
boundary=2  -Wa,-mtune=i686 -fexceptions   -I../include -I/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-
build/misc -I/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build -I../sysdeps/i386/elf -
I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686 -
I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 -
I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/pthread -
I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../sysdeps/gnu -I../sysdeps/unix/common -
I../sysdeps/unix/mman -I../sysdeps/unix/inet -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/i386 -
I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/i386 -
I../nptl/sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/posix -I../sysdeps/i386/i686/fpu -
I../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/i386/i686 -
I../sysdeps/i386/i486 -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386/i486 -I../sysdeps/i386/fpu -
I../nptl/sysdeps/i386 -I../sysdeps/i386 -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32 -
I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 -
I../sysdeps/ieee754 -I../sysdeps/generic/elf -I../sysdeps/generic -I../nptl  -I.. -
I../libio -I. -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include -isystem 
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed -isystem /tools/include -D_LIBC_REENTRANT 
-include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -o /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/misc/syslog.o 
-MD -MP -MF /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/misc/syslog.o.dt -MT /mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-
build/misc/syslog.o 
In file included from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/syslog.c:10:0:
../misc/syslog.c: In function '__vsyslog_chk':
../misc/syslog.c:144:9: warning: variable 'prioff' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-  
variable]
../misc/syslog.c:123:1: sorry, unimplemented: inlining failed in call to 'syslog':   
 function body not available
../misc/syslog.c:155:9: sorry, unimplemented: called from here
make[2]: *** [/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/misc/syslog.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.14.1/misc'
make[1]: *** [misc/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.14.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 3):

For glibc 2.15, I had to do like ks1322:

`$ ../glibc2.15/configure CFLAGS="-O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector"
$ make`

The `-O2` is required to recover the default optimisation, required to avoid a number of failures.

The `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` is required to avoid failure of `gcc ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/syslog.c` (`In function ‘__vsyslog_chk’:` [...] `inlining failed in call to ‘syslog’`)

The `-fno-stack-protector` is required to avoid failure of `gcc` [...] `elf/dl-allobjs.os libc_pic.a` (`(init-first.os):(.data+0x0): multiple definition of '__libc_multiple_libcs'`).

With these `CFLAGS`, I get just a warning (`errlist.c count 133 inflated to GLIBC_2.12 count 134 (old errno.h?)`).

P.S. It is also very important to *not* use the `gold` linker (`ld.gold`, from the `binutils-gold` package), because `libc`'s `config` will reject it. This is easily done by changing the `/usr/bin/ld` symbolic link from `ld.gold` to `ld.bfd`.

Answer (score 2):

After make failed, the following worked for me:

```
make clean
make -j2 CFLAGS="-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -O2 -fno-stack-protector"
```

See details in this blog http://www.yonch.com/tech/78-compiling-glibc.

Answer (score 1):

[glibc build issues, inlining failed](http://plash.beasts.org/wiki/GlibcBuildIssues#head-b9149fbab065967691cf1bade23d84325c05e9b0)

> Need to add -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE to the gcc invocation.

Comment: thanks...+1 for the answer...but can you tell me how to add this option while using make?

Comment: CFLAGS=-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE make

Answer (score 1):

@avinash - try the following ...

1) re-run configure ... CFLAGS="-O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" ./configure 
2) re-run make ... CFLAGS="-O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" make